# Como setar variavel no scope Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte dropdown:

```
<select> 
    <option ng-repeat="x in Ruas">{{x.Rua}}</option>
</select>
```

Eu preciso pegar o valor selecionado no dropdown (x.Rua) e setar em um atributo de outro scope chamado: casa

Answer (score 3):

Atribua o valor selecionado à uma variável do escopo indicando uma propriedade do modelo, via `ng-model`.

O exemplo a seguir armazena a seleção na propriedade `$scope.casa.rua` (assumindo que `$scope.casa` é um objeto pré-existente):

```
<select ng-model='casa.rua'> 
    <option ng-repeat="x in Ruas">{{x.Rua}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: funcionou ! obrigado OnoSendai !

Comment: Sempre um prazer ajudar!